# Cascade not working with Java

Tags: java, sqlite, cascade

I've a SQLite db with 2 tables: **Quotes** and **WPList**

the two tables have this column:

**Quotes**:  `ID (int primary key), name (String)`

**WPList**:  `ID (int primary key), ID_Quote (foreign key Quotes with cascade option), String name`

The problem is that if I execute query with an external tool (I use Navicat Essential for Mac) the `CASCADE` works correclty and if I delete a Quote all entry in WPList with his ID are eliminated. With Java this does not happen, the `CASCADE` does not work. any suggestion? thanks

EDIT.

This is the java code I use:

```
public static void deleteQuote (int ID)
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Global.dbPath);
        Statement stmt;

        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        stmt.execute("DELETE FROM Quotes WHERE ID=" + ID);

        stmt.close(); // rilascio le risorse
        conn.close(); // termino la connessione
    }

    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add the Java code you use.

Comment: Don't use freeform description of database schemas, give us the SQL statements we can copy-paste directly.

Comment: are you getting any exception ? , btw use finally block to close u r connection :)

Comment: Are you sure the quote actually deleted from the database?

Comment: Yes, the quote is correctly deleted from the Quotes table. No exception is throws and the table is alredy created I don' t have the code to create it.

Comment: @invariant what do you mean about the finally block to close the connection? thanks

Comment: let me explain why you have to use finally block , if exception happened at line stmt.execute then there is no chance of executing your conn.close() statement . for more info refer to this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Comment: I understand the need to use finally block to release resources but does not solve my problem. The Cascade still not work. Thanks!

Comment: For now I needed to simply remove the row in the WPList table manually with another query. I hope you guys can help me! thanks!!

Comment: i never said that using finally block will solve your problem , using finally block to close connections is good practice.are you getting any exceptions while running that query ?

Comment: No, no exception and the Quote row is correctly deleted but the CASCADE not working. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Are you winding up with a different version of the SQLite library in your two cases? Per [the FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q22), SQLite supports *enforcement of* foreign key constraints as of version 3.6.19.

Provided that your SQLite library is compiled with support for foreign keys, you still must enable this feature with a `pragma` statement, per [the instructions in the "Foreign Key Support" documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable). You need to evaluate the following statement:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

My guess is that your *Navicat Essential* tool is enabling foreign key support, but your Java code did not do the same.

Comment: Hi I have read this suggestion in another question and I tried to execute, before and after my query execution, a new line of cade that says: stmt.execute ("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;") but nothing happened! Thanks again

Comment: What is the actual DDL you used to create the two tables in question? The text cited in your original question would not satisfy SQLite's `CREATE TABLE` statement. http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Comment: I created the two table with Navicat Essential. If you wan' t I can do that and then paste here the code generated by Navicat to create the two tables.